# Refind: I see two files conf identical..why?

Tags: refind

I had installed refind bootloader,a simple question,why there are two identical files for configuration in different dirs?

```
/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/refind.conf
/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf
```

I have installed refind with

```
refind-install --usedefaults
```

on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Refind was installed two times
the first time by a modified ubuntu cd for some apollo-based pc
the second time by me